# mysql to mysqli php, just put "i"?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a website that is online about 5 years. just now I noticed that i use mysql connection.

I want to change it to mysqli.

So, I have some questions. 
To change mysql to mysqli I just need to put "i" after all mysql words?

query

```
eg
 $i=mysql_query("INSERT

to
 $i=mysqli_query("INSERT
```

num rows:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs);
to
$num = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
```

string escape:

```
mysql_real_escape_string
to
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

fetch arraw

```
 $l = mysql_fetch_array($re);
to
 $l = mysqli_fetch_array($re);
```

is that simple? or i need to know something else?

Comment: Please have a look at the php manual for mysqli functions http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

No it's not that simple..mysqli functions usually take a second parameter...so check the syntax of whatever functions you are changing.
For instance..instead of `mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user","my_password");` for mysqli you will use `mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`

Answer (score 0):

This will actually guide you through: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

While `mysql` was only the procedure-style function, the new `mysqli` is both: the procedure-style and object-style.

You can use the object-oriented style, like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

or procedural style:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of mysqli are reversed I.e. mysql_query($q, $dbc) becomes mysqli_query($dbc, $q). Also some functions take extra parameters, usually the connection . Php.net has a full list of all changes.

UPDATE:

```
//your connection script should look somthing like this.
$db_connnect = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db_name');

//the page you require the connection on should look something like this.
require_once ('db_connect.php');

//a mysqli query would look something like this.
$q = "select * from user limit 12";
$r = mysqli_query("$db_connnect, $q"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) { ... }
```

Comment: I use something like this: 

$users = mysql_query("select * from user limit 12");
while($usersfetch = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
...
}
my mysql_query do not have any database name and it works.
mysqli will not work?